# Functional style OOP?

Tags: oop, functional-programming

What if I make member variables as `const` as possible and treat frequently changing data as input argument to the interface method.

So instead of data owning methods that operates on itself, methods owns parameters(`const` members) and operates on data.

Is this kind of style functional or functional-style, or just call it "stateless OOP"?

Is there any reason to encourage or discourage it?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call it functional, as functional tends to imply that your program is made of composable functions (pure functions ideally).  However, the "tenets" of functional programming seem to be there- immutability, referential transparency.  The only thing you are (potentially) lacking is functions as first class objects.  To *truly* be considered functional programming you really need to have functions that are treated as first class objects- they can be assigned, passed as arguments, and returned from other functions. So I think this would be considered OOP with functional elements.

Someone who is more well-versed in programming language design feel free to modify or refute this answer!